# Concatenate and stringize macro values for #include

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, xcode, gcc

I'm trying to create a string from multiple macros/values for use in a `#include`. I'm doing this to clean up some code for an initial state in a simple state system.

I have 2 default, redefinable macros (if not defined there's a default value)

```
   #define DEFAULT_STATE          StateName    // name of class
   #define DEFAULT_STATE_LOCATION states/      // location of header file from root
```

The include directive is being used from a file 4 folders in from the `root`, so the include should look like this

```
#include "../../../../states/StateName.h"
```

based on the example above.

So I want to define a macro from the 4 values.

```
../../../../
DEFAULT_STATE_LOCATION
DEFAULT_STATE
.h
```

into some macro, say `DEFAULT_STATE_INCLUDE`

so I can say

```
#include #DEFAULT_STATE_INCLUDE
(to stringize the value for quotes)
```

That way I can change the default state and the path from the root of the header file for the default state in a prefix header, and the source using the `#include` will not have to be updated, and I can omit the constants from redefinition every time.

I'm not including the `.h` in the `DEFAULT_STATE` macro because I use the same macro to create and instance of the default state.

I've tried using the concatenation `##`, and the stringize operator, and some tricks I've found online, but nothing worked.

I can define `../../../../` and `.h` in their own macros if needed.

But simply

```
    #define DEFAULT_STATE_INCLUDE ../../../../ ## DEFAULT_STATE_LOCATION ## DEFAULT_STATE ## .h
    #include #DEFAULT_STATE_INCLUDE
```

gives tons of errors.

Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: This is normally the role of the build system to define the include path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that footnote 143 in section §6.10.2 "Source file inclusion" of the C99 standard says:

> <sup>143)</sup> Note that adjacent string literals are not concatenated into a single string literal (see the translation
>   phases in 5.1.1.2); thus, an expansion that results in two string literals is an invalid directive.

Thus, any string concatenation must be done outside the source code.  Token concatenation with `##` is not an option; that is used to build identifiers, and the bits of the header name you are joining are not identifiers.

I think you should simply use something like:

```
#ifndef STATE_HEADER
#define STATE_HEADER "states/StateName.h"
#endif
#include STATE_HEADER
```

and leave it to the build system, not the source code, to determine that `-I../../../..` is required as an option to the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

You'd better pass the include directory to gcc with `-I` option

```
-I../../../..
```

From gcc man page:

```
-I dir
Add the directory dir to the list of directories to be searched for header files.
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems relevant: [Computed Includes](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Computed-Includes.html)

My reading of that is that the #define macro has to include the " (quote) characters and that you can't rely on the stringize or concatenation operators to do it for you.

Comment: Not quite: you can rely on the stringize and concatenation operators, and you can use the `<>` form, it's just that all of those are very tricky to use correctly. For an example not mentioned on that page, `#include HEADER(errno)` where `HEADER(x)` is defined as `<x.h>` is valid -- as long as `errno` is not already defined as a macro. If it is, then things break, rather badly.

Comment: How would you get this to work if errno is a macro? If I could do that and just use 2 arguments to pass in the location and name macros, this would work fine

Comment: @user1137704 Short answer: you can't. Longer answer: the only way to prevent macro expansion when errno appears as a separate token is to use the stringize operator directly, without a second macro expansion. But in that case, you just get `"errno"`, which is useless for your purposes. To conclude, see short answer.